# Python generate random 128 bit strings

Tags: python, random, bit

I need to generate several random strings for later use of length 128 bit (or 16 bytes, 32 hex characters).
I have used this until now:

```
hex(random.getrandbits(128))[2:]
```

Unfortunately it turns out that it does not consistently produce 32 hex characters which is a requirement of my implementation. Some strings it produces are shorter than others, i.e. 30 or 31 characters, which is a problem.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(16)
'S\x0e\xac\x91m\xcf\xf1\xae\x9b5\xf9A\xf3\xa2\xf9@'
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach should **consistently** produce a **printable** 32 character hex string from a pseudorandom 128 bit integer. It left pads with zeros, of course. Moreover, I believe this to be the simplest way to do it.

```py
> import random

> randint = random.getrandbits(128)
> randstr = f'{randint:032x}'
> print(randstr)
00424c4bcbd1c00e3f4dd2bc52b2776b
```

Here is the code to test the output length:

```
import random

for i in range(1_000_000):
    randint = random.getrandbits(128)
    randstr = f'{randint:032x}'
    assert isinstance(randstr, str)
    assert (randint == int(randstr, 16)), (randint, randstr)
    assert (len(randstr) == 32), (randstr, len(randstr))
    assert (randstr == randstr.strip()), repr(randstr)
    print(randstr)
```

Comment: getting this error--> "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'